# Custom array adapter doesn't work in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I want to populate a list view with custom array adapter, however it looks like getView() is never called. Below is my code, this part creates the dialog:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            //do deletion
        }
    })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // User cancelled the dialog
                }
            });
    builder.setTitle("Dialog title").setView(getCustomView());
    return builder.create();
}
```

This part creates the view, I commented on which works, which doesn't

```
public View getCustomView(){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_delete_option, null);
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listDelOptions);

    /*this is default array adapter, works */
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("del one");
    list.add("del all");
    ArrayAdapter<String> defaultAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, list);

    /*this is custom adapter, NOT working */
    mAdapter = new DeleteAdapter(getActivity(),0); //last int is not used since we
    //know which layout to inflate

    //NOT working
    //listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    //working
    listView.setAdapter(defaultAdapter);
    return view;
}
```

This is the custom array adapter, only `getView` is relevant, but post here the whole class in case.

```
public static class DeleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
    private final int mLayoutId;
    private int mCheckPos;
    Context mContext;
    String [] mButtonDescription;

    public DeleteAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
        mLayoutId= R.layout.delete_list_item_view;
        mContext = context;
        mCheckPos = 0;
        mButtonDescription = new String[3];
        mButtonDescription[0] = context.getString(R.string.del_only_this_event);
        mButtonDescription[1] = context.getString(R.string.del_this_and_future_events);
        mButtonDescription[2] = context.getString(R.string.del_all_events);

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view =convertView;
        if (view==null){
            view =  View.inflate(mContext,mLayoutId, null);
        }
        RadioButton button = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.rdDelOption);
        button.setTag(new Integer(position));
        button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkedChangeListener);
        if (position== mCheckPos)
            button.setChecked(true);
        else
            button.setChecked(false);
        button.setText(mButtonDescription[position]);
        return  view;
    }

    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener checkedChangeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                mCheckPos =  (Integer) buttonView.getTag();//tag is the position
            }
        }
    };


    public int getSelectedItem(){
        return mCheckPos;
    }

}
```

What's wrong with my DeleteAdapter? Thanks.

Comment: how many items are there in your list ? This can be provided by overriding getCount() method in the adapter. you should let the arrayadapter know how many items are there in the list by either passing the list of objects in constructor or by overriding getcount.

Comment: excellent answer, after adding `getCount()` the list items show. Thanks

Comment: i have similar problem. my problem is imageView visible invisible not working inside DialogFragment Custom ArrayAdapter. plz help me..